# Is there a way to set Security Settings" -> "Local Policies" -> "Security Options" using powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure, security

I searched it quite a bit but could not find an easy/straightforward working answer.

I want to update a "Security Option" on windows 10. Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> Security Options via powershell script.
The PC is not part of any domain.
(it is a VM in Azure).
Is there any cmdlet that will help in editing the values of enteries in "Security Options"

Comment: Export a security template using the Security Templates MMC, use `secedit` on the target machine to import the template

Comment: Sounds like an option. However, I am not fan of maintaining a template for only one setting.  I want to have something "name/value" pair option to just change one security setting.

Comment: + I am assuming I do not have any reference machine.

Comment: Most of the Security Options have been there for a looooong time, unless you're looking for options new to Windows 10 you can use an earlier version to author the template. What setting are interested in?

Comment: On Windows 10,  under security options "User Accouont Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account" I cant see it when I do secedit /export /cfg %PATH%

Comment: By default this option is set to "undefined" and when I export the sec config using secedit, it does not contain this setting. However, if I set it to either enabled or disabled, secedit export contains the setting as "MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\FilterAdministratorToken=4,1". Anyways, I got the job done somehow.

Comment: for a newly installed system:  I did secedit /export /cfg to a file, edited that file and added the setting and then imported that updated file to the system.

Answer (score 1):

For the product I work on, it's imperative that the process is automated. I built on @Muhammad Faizan-Ul-Haq's procedure, reading out the local policy INF file line by line, substituting updated rules and then writing the updated file back using Power Shell.
The code below could be made more generic, but does work on Windows 10.

```
$DefaultPolicyINF  = "C:\Windows\INF\defltbase.inf"
$NewPolicyINF      = "C:\Users\temp\NewPolicyFile.inf"
$SecureEdit        = "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SecEdit" 
$BlockRemoteLogons = "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight = RDP Logon Block"

New-Item  $NewPolicyINF  -type  file 

foreach( $line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( $DefaultPolicyINF ) ) 
{      
       if( $line.Contains( "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" ) )
       {
           Add-Content -Path $NewPolicyINF -Value $BlockRemoteLogons
       }
       else
       {
           Add-Content -Path $NewPolicyINF -Value $line
       }
 }
 
 & $SecureEdit /configure /cfg $NewPolicyINF /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
 
 if ( Test-Path  $NewPolicyINF   ) {    Remove-Item $NewPolicyINF   }
 if ( Test-Path  "defltbase.jfm" ) {    Remove-Item "defltbase.jfm" }
 if ( Test-Path  "defltbase.sdb" ) {    Remove-Item "defltbase.sdb" }
```